# javascript text element without new line ; button visibility

Tags: javascript

how can I add a text element in javascript without new line ? Both < p> and < br> begin with new line...

How can I make button hidden - statically and dynamically ?
for static - this didnt work -

```
    <input type="button" name="b_two" value="Next" onclick="foo()" visibility="hidden" />
```

for dynamic -

```
     document.getElementById("b_two").style.visibility= "hidden";
```

Comment: `visibility="hidden"` isn't valid. It should be `style="visibility:hidden"` or `style="display:none"`

Comment: Correction to first question -  how to text element in HTML without new line... Seems like dd is the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS `display` property

```
<input type="button" name="b_two" value="Next" onclick="foo()" style="display:none;" />
```